# Pipe viewer for windows platform

Tags: windows, linux, performance

I'm looking for an alternative tool to sniff/monitor/measure performance of pipes on the Windows platform. Just like you can use pipe viewer (pv) on Linux (https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv).

I found only a Cygwin variant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504204/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-alternative-to-pipe-viewer-for-windows-platform#

Are there any non-Cygwin native Windows variants out there? If not, what other tool could you use to measure what is written to the console?

Br, Johan